# Enable guest user not working

Tags: windows-8, cmd.exe, user, guest-account

I would like to activethe guest user in cmd or gpo:

Invité = Guest (I'm french), using Guest return an error.

**CMD** : `net user Invité /active:yes`

I've got "The command completed successfully" but my guest user is still off (I see it on the logon screen and into the Manage Account)...

The command succeedded if I've already activate the account into the Manage Account by myself...

**GPO** : I enable this one **Accounts: Guest account status** at *Computer Configuration/Windows Settings/Security Settings/Local Policies/Security Options* but it's not working too...

I'm missing something ?

**EDIT** : I also tried `secpol.msc>security setting>security options>Guest account status` but it's still disabled...

Comment: **What was the error?**

Comment: There is no error. The response of my command is "The command completed successfully" but my guest account is still disabled.
But I enable this one mannualy and after that the command with yes or no parameter works successfully.